# SilverStripe form pagination

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using a form on a SilverStripe page, the form is currently quite long. I am looking for a way where I can paginate the form. I would like to have 5 fields showing. Once them fields are filled out the user could then click next and be shown the next 5 fields. Also a previous button would be required. Thanks for your help if you need any more info let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look into the [multi-step-form module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-multiform) : "MultiForm is a SilverStripe module, allowing flow control for forms, and step process to be automatically determined based on configuration variables on each step class. It augments the existing Form class in SilverStripe."

I believe this allows you to do what you need.  The github repository has a complete example to set up and I recommend reading it in detail.